# Bluebird map returning early

Tags: javascript, mongodb, bluebird

I am using `Bluebird.map` but it is returning my array of objects early for some reason:

```
function returnInvoicePrice(items) {
    return Bluebird.map(items, function(item) {
        db.collection('products').find({
            product_code    : item.product_code
        }).toArray(function(err, product) {
            var invoice_price = product[0].invoice_price;
            console.log('--product--');
            console.log(product);
            return product;
        });
    }).then(function(items) {
        console.log('--items w/ invoice price--'); // this prints BEFORE my console.log(product) for some reason...
        console.log(items);
    }).catch(function(error) {
       console.log('--bluebird error in returning price for each item--');
       console.log(error);
    });
}

returnInvoicePrice(items);
```

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see three main things wrong here:

1. Bluebirds `.map()` needs a callback that returns a promise.
2. Your `.then()` handle that is doing `console.log(items)` must `return items` so that the result promise still has `items` as the resolved value.
3. When you call `returnInvoicePrice()` you have to use `.then()` to retrieve it's value.  That function returns a promise that is a master promise that watches all the other promises in `.map()`.

**The function that you pass to `Bluebird.map()` needs to return a promise** that is resolved when that async operation is finished.  If it returns nothing or returns a plain value, then Bluebird cannot wait until the async operation is complete and thus will return sooner than you want.

If your version does not yet support promises, there are packages out there such as [mongodb-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-promise) that will provide you a promise interface to mongodb or you can use Bluebird's `.promisify()` or `.promisifyAll()` to promisify interfaces in mongodb.

The latest version of mongodb for node supports promises in all its async interfaces so you can directly return the promises it offers.

It appears from [this doc for the latest mongodb](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#find) that `xxx.find().toArray()` returns a promise so you can return that promise directly from the `.map()` callback like this (and also fix the other things wrong):

```
function returnInvoicePrice(items) {
    return Bluebird.map(items, function(item) {
        // return promise here
        return db.collection('products').find({
            product_code    : item.product_code
        }).toArray(function(err, product) {
            var invoice_price = product[0].invoice_price;
            console.log('--product--');
            console.log(product);
            return product;
        });
    }).then(function(items) {
        console.log('--items w/ invoice price--'); // this prints BEFORE my console.log(product) for some reason...
        console.log(items);
        // also have to return items here
        return items;
    }).catch(function(error) {
       console.log('--bluebird error in returning price for each item--');
       console.log(error);
    });
}

// have to use `.then()` on the returned promise here
returnInvoicePrice(items).then(function(items) {
    // can access items here
});
```

Comment: Added code example and pointed out two other things wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you run this code:

```
var Bluebird = require('bluebird');

function returnInvoicePrice(items) {
  return Bluebird.map(items, function(item) {
    console.log(item);
    return item;
  }).then(function(items) {
    console.log('--items w/ invoice price--'); // this prints BEFORE my console.log(product) for some reason...
    console.log(items);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log('--bluebird error in returning price for each item--');
    console.log(error);
  });
}

returnInvoicePrice([1,2,3]);
```

You will see the order you are expecting.  The difference is, as jfriend00 alludes to is that the db.collection.find(...) is asynchronous, executing at some future point. So you would need to wrap that portion in a Promise:

```
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  db.collection.find({
   :
    resolve();   // this will signal Bluebird to execute the mapper function
  });
}
```

That way, Bluebird knows to wait for the response before continuing.

You can see this by running this code which simulates an asynch process:

```
var Bluebird = require('bluebird');

function returnInvoicePrice(items) {
  return Bluebird.map(items, function(item) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(item);
        resolve(item);
      }, 500);
    });
  }).then(function(items) {
    console.log('--items w/ invoice price--'); // this prints BEFORE my console.log(product) for some reason...
    console.log(items);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log('--bluebird error in returning price for each item--');
    console.log(error);
  });
}

returnInvoicePrice([1,2,3]);
```

Comment: Why down vote something without providing a comment??

Comment: Your promise wrapper around `db.collection.find()` assumes that `.find()` is synchronous and simply won't work.  In addition, there are multiple other and better ways to get promises for use with mongodb.  The latest version includes promises built-in and, if you're not using that version for some reason, there are modules that promisify the whole library.  And, `returnInvoicePrice()` returns a promise so you have to use `.then()` on it.  And, the first `.then()` handler must `return items` or the resolved value of the promise becomes `undefined`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to put the resolve() inside the contained function. I have edited it.

Comment: Regarding the use or promises, Bluebird provides promises and given I don't know the op's version of mongoDB I used that.  I agree that using mongoDB's promises could be an improvement if the op has a recent version.

Comment: `resolve()` needs to go inside a callback that is passed to `db.collection.find()`.  Your updated version shows it inside an object definition, not inside a callback.

Comment: Bluebird also provides `.promisfy()` and `.promisifyAll()` so if you were going to manually promisify, you should at least use those.  There are just no reasons to manually promisify a single method in mongodb.  You can either use a modern version that has promises built in, you can use a pre-built module that promisifies it all for you or since the OP is already using Bluebird, you can use its promisification functions.